# How to make so that in the inspector I chose what method to me to use?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Script has two methods. How to make so that in the inspector I chose what method to me to use.

```
public void PrintHello()
{
    Debug.Log("Hello");
}

public void PrintHowAreYou()
{
    Debug.Log("How are you?");
}
```

these methods I wrote as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) to allow you pick a function from the Editor Inspector tab.

Declare it as:

```
public UnityEvent method;
```

From the Editor, you can select the GameObject this script is attached to, the name of the script then the function.

If you need to call that method, it is really easy to do:

```
void Start()
{
    method.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking on the check-mark image on the left side of it. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) post for more information